# How to handle a large set of data using Spring Data Repositories?

Tags: spring, repository, spring-data

I have a large table that I'd like to access via a Spring Data Repository.

Currently, I'm trying to extend the `PagingAndSortingRepository` interface but it seems I can only define methods that return lists, eg.:

```
public interface MyRepository extends 
        PagingAndSortingRepository<MyEntity, Integer>
{
  @Query(value="SELECT * ...")
  List<MyEntity> myQuery(Pageable p);
}
```

On the other hand, the `findAll()` method that comes with `PagingAndSortingRepository` returns an `Iterable` (and I suppose that the data is not loaded into memory).

Is it possible to define custom queries that also return Iterable and/or don't load all the data into memory at once?

Are there any alternatives for handling large tables?

Comment: `List` implements the `Iterable` interface, so your custom query method does return an `Iterable`.

Comment: I suppose that Spring Data doesn't load everything in memory when I use findAll(), am I wrong? I will edit the question.

Comment: The [underlying implementation](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L247) simply retrieves a list, so it's not that sophisticated.

Comment: I see, thank you for the explanation. By the way, how would you solve the problem? Is using Pageable parameters the only way not to load everything into memory?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We have the classical consulting answer here: it depends. As the implementation of the method is store specific, we depend on the underlying store API. In case of JPA there's no chance to provide streaming access as `….getResultList()` returns a `List`. Hence we also expose the `List` to the client as especially JPA developers might be used to working with lists. So for JPA the only option is using the pagination API.

For a store like Neo4j we support the streaming access as the repositories return `Iterable` on CRUD methods as well as on the execution of finder methods.

Comment: Hi Oliver, thanks for the explanation. I created an Iterable to abstract the pagination stuff. If you have some time, I would really appreciate any feedback about the code/approach. Thank you again :)

https://gist.github.com/josericardo/5102304

Comment: I'd generally recommend not do things like these. It's easy to hand around a wrapper that silently fetches data but you'll run into all sorts of issues as you don't really have control over the session boundary so that you run into `LazyLoadingException`. What's wrong with accessing a `Page`, iterating over the content and repeat that if `Page.hasNext()` is `true`? This at least makes obvious that you get session boundaries at the repository level unless you're in a broader scoped transaction.

Answer (score 8):

The [implementation](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L247) of `findAll()` simply loads the entire list of all entities into memory. Its `Iterable` return type doesn't imply that it implements some sort of database level cursor handling.

On the other hand your custom `myQuery(Pageable)` method will only load one page worth of entities, because the generated implementation honours its `Pageable` parameter. You can declare its return type either as `Page` or `List`. In the latter case you still receive the same (restricted) number of entities, but not the metadata that a `Page` would additionally carry.

So you basically did the right thing to avoid loading all entities into memory in your custom query.

Please review the [related documentation here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters).

Comment: The second link is broken. Now it's https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is *Spring Data JPA Stream*. It brings a significant performance boost to data fetching particularly in databases with millions of record. In your case you have several options which you can consider

1. Pull all data once in memory
2. Use pagination and read pages each time
3. Use something like Apache Spark
4. Streaming data using Spring Data JPA

In order to make Spring Data JPA Stream to work, we need to modify our `MyRepository` to return `Stream<MyEntity>` like this:

```
public interface MyRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyEntity, Integer> {
    @QueryHints(value = {
        @QueryHint(name = HINT_CACHEABLE, value = "false"),
        @QueryHint(name = READ_ONLY, value = "true")
    })
    @Query(value="SELECT * ...")
    Stream<MyEntity> myQuery();
}
```

In this example, we disable second level caching and hint Hibernate that the entities will be read only. If your requirement is different, make sure to change those settings accordingly for your requirements.